# How is this probability generating function in regard to branching obtained

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, markov-chains, generating-functions

Suppose we have a branching process $\{X_{n} : n=0,1,2,.. \}$ with $X_{0}=1$, pgf of these $\phi_{X_{1}}(z)=\phi(z)$

and

$S_{n}=X_{0}+X_{1}+...+X_{n}$ , which we assume has pgf $\Phi_{n}(z)$

How to show that

$\Phi_{n+1}(z)=z \phi[ \Phi_{n}(z)]$

My issue is that I dont understand where the z on the right hand side would be coming from. Also, is writing $\Phi_{n}$ equivalent to just writing $\Phi_{Sn}$  if so

$\Phi_{n} (z)=E[z^{Sn}]$

by total expectation

$= E_{X_{1}}[E[z^{Sn}|X_{1}]$

The main thing that I have been trying to work out is how knowing $X1$ allows us to rewrite $S_{n}$ and then how the generating functions represent that.

It is important to realise that this is not talking about how many are in the nth generation, but how many total, ie the sum of all the generations up to and before it
And yes it does seem that the $z$ factor will be as $X_{0}$ is fixed and hence indepdent of any generation size. But I still dont know how to use the generating functions to achieve the full result
so can anyone help me to see where I am going wrong and or where I am making a mistake in my understanding? Please let me know if there is some info that isnt clear

Thanks

Comment: How do you get $\Phi_{n+1}(z)=[\phi(z)]^{n+1}$? $X_n$ aren't independent, so the expectation of the product isn't the product of expectations.

Comment: Also, just looking at it, is it possible that $z$ is coming from $X_0 =1$ which is independent of the rest?

Comment: Hint: Condition on the value of $X_1$. If $X_1=k$ then imaging $k$ of the original branching process and write $\Phi_{n+1}$ in terms of that

Comment: @nullUser  , Do you mean I should compute $\Phi$ using the expectation directly, and use law of total expectation to do it?  I updated

Comment: But I am having trouble seeing how conditioning on $X_{1}$ can tell us any info to use for Sn

Comment: On the event $\{X_1=k\}$, one has $S_{n+1}=1+S^{(1)}_n+S^{(2)}_n+\cdots+S^{(k)}_n$, where the random variables $(S^{(i)}_n)_{i\geqslant1}$ are i.i.d. and distributed like $S_n$. In words, $1$ stands for the root and $S^{(i)}_n$ for the descendants of the $i$th direct descendant of the root. Thus the identity with generating functions.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but why wouldn't the sum have  a +k? because we have the root , 1, and it gives rise to k individuals, and each of these k gives rise to a number of individuals denoted as above, for example say the root gave rise to (1 , 2 , 3) and 1 gave rise to (4,5)  2 gave rise to nothing and 3 to (6,7,8), and then suppose they all stopped, then from that definition we have $S^{1}=2$ , $S^{2}=0$ and $S^{3}=3$ which is a sum of$1+2+0+3=6$ but we really have 9 total. Am I misinterpreting what you said?

Comment: In your example the subtrees rooted at 1, 2, 3 have sizes 3, 1 and 4 respectively (one should count their roots...) hence indeed 9=1+(3+1+4). // Two remarks: First, next time you comment on a comment, please use @. Second, FYI, I disagree that "This question has not received enough attention", rather, the answers you got might have not received enough attention from you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $z$ define the map $g_z(w)=\phi(zw)$. For fixed but arbitrary $n$ we show that

\begin{align*}
\tag{1} E(z^{S_{n+1}})=E(z^{S_{n+1-k}}(g_z^{(k)}(1))^{X_{n+1-k}})
\end{align*}

for all $k\leq n+1$, where $g_z^{(k)}$ is the $k$-fold composition of $g_z$. $g_z^{(0)}$ should be interpreted as the constant map identically equal to $1$. The $k=0$ case holds by definition.

Assume $(1)$ holds for some $k\leq n$. Then,

$
\begin{align*}
E(z^{S_{n+1}})&=E(z^{S_{n+1-k}}(g_z^{(k)}(1))^{X_{n+1-k}}) \\
&=E(E(z^{S_{n+1-k}}(g_z^{(k)}(1))^{X_{n+1-k}}\mid X_1,\dots, X_{n-k})) \\
&=E(z^{S_{n-k}}E(z^{X_{n+1-k}}(g_z^{(k)}(1))^{X_{n+1-k}}\mid X_1,\dots, X_{n-k})) \\
&=E(z^{S_{n-k}}\mid E((zg_z^{(k)}(1))^{X_{n+1-k}}\mid X_1,\dots, X_{n-k})) \\
&=E(z^{S_{n-k}}\phi(zg_z^{(k)}(1))^{X_{n-k}}) \\
&=E(z^{S_{n-k}}g_z^{(k+1)}(1)^{X_{n-k}})
\end{align*}
$

so formula $(1)$ holds also for $k+1$, showing that it holds true in general. We may therefore set $k=n+1$ in $(1)$ and use the fact that $S_0=X_0=1$ to get the equation $$E(z^{S_{n+1}})=zg_z^{(n+1)}(1)$$ which holds for all $n$. Note that this is actually the explicit solution.

Finally,

$
\begin{align*}
z\phi(E(z^{S_n}))&=z\phi(zg_z^{(n)}(1)) \\
&=zg_z^{(n+1)}(1) \\
&=E(z^{S_{n+1}}).
\end{align*}
$

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do the recursion.
I describe here the top-bottom approach.
For the bottom-up approach you may look at the comment above by Didier.

The important point is that given $X_j$ then $X_{j+1}$ comes
from a sum of $X_j$  independent copies of branchings
each following the law of $X_1$. In terms of  an auxiliary variable $s$ we may express this as follows:
$$ E\left(s^{X_{j+1}} \ | \ X_j\right) =
\phi(s)^{X_{j}}
$$
Let us write $\Phi_0(z)=z$ and for $k\geq 0$: 
$$\Phi_{k+1}(z) \ =z \ \phi \left[ \Phi_k(z) \right].$$

I then claim that for $n\geq k \geq 0$ we have the (inductive)  identity
(we set $S_{-1}=0$):

$$ E\left(z^{S_{n-k}} \Phi_{k}(z)^{X_{n-k+1}} \right) =
 E\left(z^{S_{n-k-1}} \Phi_{k+1}(z)^{X_{n-k}}\right) 
$$

To see this note that by conditioning on $X_{n-k}$ and using the first identity above with $s=\Phi_{k}(z)$ and $j=n-k$, the LHS equals:
$$ E\left(E\left(z^{S_{n-k-1}} \; 
 z^{X_{n-k}}\Phi_{k}(z)^{X_{n-k+1}}\  |\ X_{n-k}\right)\right) 
= E\left(E\left(z^{S_{n-k-1}} \; 
\ z^{X_{n-k}}\phi\left[ \Phi_{k}(z)\right]^{X_{n-k}}\  
|\ X_{n-k}\right)\right) 
$$
which reduces to the RHS of the previous equation given the recursive definition of $\Phi_{k+1}$. Thus,
carrying out the induction:
$$
E\left(z^{S_{n+1}}  \right) =
 E\left(z^{S_{n}} \Phi_{0}(z)^{X_{n+1}}\right)  = ... =
 E\left(z^{S_{-1}} \Phi_{n+1}(z)^{X_{0}}\right) =\Phi_{n+1}(z)
$$

Comment: Each $S_n$ is the total size of the $n$ first generations, not the size of the $n$th generation only. See my comment on main for the proper computation.

Comment: Where is the z factor?

Comment: I have inserted an extra intermediate calculation in the second last equation array. The z factor comes from $z^{X_n}$ which combines with $\phi(\Phi_0(z))^{X_n}$ to give $\Phi_1(z)^{X_n}$, and then you iterate.